# Canvas does not appear python 2

Tags: python, canvas

I am running a simple little test program in python 2, but the canvas is not appearing.

```
    from Tkinter import *   
    tk = Tk()   
    canvas = Canvas(tk, width=600, height=600)   
    canvas.pack()   
    canvas.create_rectangle(250, 250, 350, 350)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter need to pack your frame. :-p

add

tk.mainloop()

to the end of your program

By the way, canvas is also in same colour as tkinter frame. So, consider adding colour to canvas. So, that you can identify it.

canvas.config(bg = 'Black')

Comment: There is no frame to pack, but you are correct about calling `mainloop`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solved my problem. The canvas is now appearing.